# JTextField is Too big in the event handled JFrame

Tags: java, jtextfield

I'm new to JAVA Programming and I'm trying to make a memory modification GUI program below is the code. MY JTextField is too big any suggestions on how to fix this problem? also I would appreciate if an alternate way was found to do the mentioned task. Thank you for your time

```
JMenuBar menubar;
JMenu data,array,linkedlist,strings,stacks,tree,graphs,queues;
JMenuItem dtypeint,dtypefloat,dtypechar;

public GUI(){
    super("Data Structures Assignment");
    System.out.println("Select the Above mentioned Options for Memory Modification");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    menubar = new JMenuBar();
    add(menubar);

    data = new JMenu("Basic Data Types");
    menubar.add(data);

    array = new JMenu("Arrays");
    menubar.add(array);

    linkedlist = new JMenu("Linked List");
    menubar.add(linkedlist);

    strings = new JMenu("Strings");
    menubar.add(strings);

    stacks = new JMenu("Stacks");
    menubar.add(stacks);

    tree = new JMenu("Tree");
    menubar.add(tree);

    graphs = new JMenu("Graphs");
    menubar.add(graphs);

    queues = new JMenu("Queues");
    menubar.add(queues);

    dtypeint = new JMenuItem("Integer");
    data.add(dtypeint);

    dtypefloat = new JMenuItem("Float");
    data.add(dtypefloat);

    dtypechar = new JMenuItem("Character");
    data.add(dtypechar);

    setJMenuBar(menubar);

    thehandler handler = new thehandler();
    dtypeint.addActionListener(handler);
    dtypefloat.addActionListener(handler);
    dtypechar.addActionListener(handler);
}
private class thehandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        if(event.getSource()==dtypeint){
            setLayout(new GridLayout());
            Frame F = new JFrame();
            F.setVisible(true);
            F.setSize(200,200);
            final JTextField item1;
            item1 = new JTextField("Word Size");
            item1.setColumns(15);
            F.add(item1);

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you can set size for you text field by using setSize() method.

Comment: @RameshK, The job of the layout manager is to determine the size of the component based on the rules of the layout manager. Invoking setSize() will have no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Remove `F.setSize(200,200)`.
- After your `F.add(item1)` line, add `F.pack()`.
- Finally, move the `F.setVisible(true)` line so it comes after the `F.pack()` line;  you should not show a Frame until you have finished building it.

The `pack()` method sets a window's size to accommodate the preferred sizes of the components it contains.

Answer (score 1):

The default layout of a JFrame is the BoderLayout. By default a component is added to the CENTER of the BorderLayout and will be sized to take up all the available space. So you need to use the proper combination of layout managers to get your desired effect.

Maybe somehting like:

```
//F.add(item1);
JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // uses FlowLayout by default
panel.add(item1);
F.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples.